# How can I make to typescript to infer generic type map

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript does not infer generic types.

I want to make FormField component that use factory pattern.

So I made mapping types.

```
import { Editor } from "@/components";
import { InputProps, NumberInputProps } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ValueOf } from "type-fest";

export const FormFieldTypes = {
  String: "string",
  Number: "number",
  Document: "document",
} as const;

export type FormFieldTypes = ValueOf<typeof FormFieldTypes>;

export type FormFieldPropsTypeMap = {
  [FormFieldTypes.String]: InputProps;
  [FormFieldTypes.Number]: NumberInputProps;
  [FormFieldTypes.Document]: React.ComponentProps<typeof Editor>;
};
```

Then, I made component that use above types.

```
import { FormFieldPropsTypeMap, FormFieldTypes } from "@/constants";
import { Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ForwardedRef, forwardRef, useMemo } from "react";
import { Control, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Editor, WithFormLabel } from "..";

type FormFieldProps<T extends FormFieldTypes> = {
  fieldType: T;
  name: string;
  control?: Control<any, any>;
  label?: string;
} & Omit<FormFieldPropsTypeMap[T], "name">;

const FormFieldBase = <T extends FormFieldTypes>(
  { fieldType, name, label, control, ...rest }: FormFieldProps<T>,
  ref: ForwardedRef<unknown>
) => {
  const field = useMemo(() => {
    switch (fieldType) {
      case FormFieldTypes.String:
        return (
          <Input
            ref={ref}
            {...(rest as FormFieldPropsTypeMap[typeof FormFieldTypes.String])}
          />
        );
      case FormFieldTypes.Document:
        return (
          <Controller
            name={name}
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => {
              return (
                <Editor
                  defaultValue={value ?? "Hello, World!"}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  {...(rest as FormFieldPropsTypeMap[typeof FormFieldTypes.Document])}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
        );
    }
  }, [control, fieldType, name, ref, rest]);

  return (
    <>{label ? <WithFormLabel label={label}>{field}</WithFormLabel> : field}</>
  );
};

const FormField = forwardRef(FormFieldBase);

FormField.displayName = "FormField";

export default FormField as <T extends FormFieldTypes>(
  props: FormFieldProps<T> & { ref?: ForwardedRef<unknown> }
) => ReturnType<typeof FormFieldBase>;
```

fieldType and FormFieldPropsTypeMap mapped with generic.

So, I think if fieldType refined by switch-cases, FormFieldPropsTypeMap is also refined.

But, typescript can't infer type of FormFieldPropsTypeMap properly.

Typescript inferred type of "rest" to

```
rest: Omit<FormFieldProps<T>, "name" | "fieldType" | "label" | "control">
```

How can I get refined type?

For now, I just use type assertion.

Comment: But, that *is* the right type... right? That's what you want, functionally. Are you just asking how to expand it so you can see the "full" type?